# How to assign a value as key with new value in JSON items?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two pieces of data, the first is a json result (shortened, clipped here) -

`hold['results']['concepts']`

```
[
    {
        'dbpedia_resource':'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder',
        'relevance': 0.946535,
        'text': 'Posttraumatic stress disorder'
    },
    {
        'dbpedia_resource': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hypnotherapy',
        'relevance': 0.870893,
        'text': 'Hypnotherapy'
    }
]
```

The second is the value of 175.

I want to unite them with each other so that it appears as:

```
[
    {
        'Posttraumatic stress disorder': 175
    },
    {
        'Hypnotherapy': 175
    }
]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself!

```
dicts={}

for i in hold['results']['concepts']:
    dummy=i['text']
    dict1 = {dummy:175}
    dicts.update(dict1)
```